# Anchor html (<a>) just works for right click not left click

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have an anchor tag as following that does not work for left click. At present, users need to right click on it to open it because left click does not work. Once I left click on the links the `display` style of `<li>` of the clicked anchor gets changed.

Issue: Click on Download PDFs > Click on Sample 1 (does not work)

```
<html>
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <ol class="myList">
            <li class="showList"><a href=""><img
                    src="http://www.example.com/image.png" />Download PDFs</a>
                <div class="pdfFiles">
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/sample1.pdf"><i
                                class="fa fa-file-pdf-o f24"></i> Sample 1</a>
                            <div class="pdfSize">10MB</div></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
         </ol>
</body>
<style>
.myList {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.myList>li {
    padding-top: 1%;
}

.myList li.showList {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, GhostWhite, #aca696) repeat
        scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.myList li .pdfFiles {
    transition: all 1.5s ease 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    /* the last value is the transition-delay for visibility */
    display: none;
    height: auto;
}

.myList li .pdfFiles li {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px
}

.myList li .pdfFiles li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.pdfSize {
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
</style>
<script>
    $('.showList a').click(function() {
        $('pdfFiles').hide();
        $(this).siblings().toggle();
        return false;
    })
</script>
</html>
```

**The address has http://**

Comment: Why is your anchor in italics? Try wrapping the entire anchor code in italics - `<i><a href="your-link-here">Link</a></i>`

Comment: @BrianBennett It’s something with FontAwesome. Those `i` tags get replaced by some symbol, I think.

Comment: Are you using some kind of JavaScript library? I can't reproduce the problem in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hnyq2yum/

Comment: I couldn't replicate it either. It sounds like there's some JS involved because he mentions clicking an `<li>` to change the display style. It may be caching other links on the page...

Comment: @BrianBennett Xufox is correct they are used for FontAwesome library.

Comment: @BrianBennett question is rephrased sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @Xufox you are right they are related to FontAwesome

Comment: Please show any CSS relevant to the links.

Comment: You have two anchor tags - which one isn't working correctly?

Comment: @timgavin 'Sample 1' anchor

Comment: your link is going to `sample1.PFG` not `sample1.PDF`. is that the problem?

Comment: @timgavin- Good guess, although both of those pages lead to the same page. So that's probably not it.

Comment: @timgavin no that was a typo

Comment: @DanielNewtown It's in your jQuery. Full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your jQuery. You're using the anchor tag to toggle the sibling `div`, but you're not limiting the selection to *only* the first anchor tag. So, when you click on the PDF file to download, it toggles the script again.

Change your script to this:

```
 $('.showList a:first').click(function() {
        $('pdfFiles').hide();
        $(this).siblings().toggle();
        return false;
    })
```

Here's a **[working CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/jPBPJO)**.

Answer (score 2):

This feels like something basic I must be missing, but:

`<a href="www.example.com/sample1.pfg">`

can't work. Because it doesn't have a protocol prefix (e.g. "http://"), the browser will interpret it as a relative link, and try to fetch a page with that path starting from its present location, rather than from example.com.

Edit: the correct syntax would be:
`<a href="http://www.example.com/sample1.pfg">` 
- assuming, of course, there really is such a file at that location.

How right-click works, though, I'm at a loss to explain.

Comment: Might work on right click because it opens it in a new tab (?)

Comment: Even adding http does not solve the problem, http : // www.example.com/sample.pdf does not work.